# DockLayoutPanel doesn't work properly

Tags: java, css, gwt, docklayoutpanel

I describe my panel in next way

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
         xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
<g:DockLayoutPanel unit="PX" width="600" >
    <g:north size="85">
    ....
    </g:north>
    <g:center>
    ....

    </g:center>
</g:DockLayoutPanel>
```

GWT generated for north and center next divs.

```
 <div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; height: 85px;"
 <div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 85px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
```

They contains data that what I need, but second div doesn't displayed. Where I am wrong?

**UPD:**
Just for example, for

```
    <g:center>
        <g:FlowPanel height="100%">
            <g:Label height="100%">TEST2</g:Label>
        </g:FlowPanel>
    </g:center>
```

I get

```
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 85px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 85px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
    <div style="height: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
        <div class="gwt-Label" style="height: 100%;">TEST2</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what are the contents of <center> ?

Comment: @Travis, I provided some example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I know what you did wrong.
You need this:

```
RootLayoutPanel().get().add(new MyView());
```

instead of:

```
RootPanel().get().add(new MyView());
```

Because if you use uibinder you need the RootLayouPanel!

I hope it will help you!

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was what I need. I will give you bounty for this answer.

Comment: I'm using RootPanel with uibinder it its working just fine. Interesting.

Comment: @Travis, It seems that you need use `RootLayoutPanel` for some features of `*LayoutPanel`. RootPanel works well with _uibinder_ but not with `LayoutPanel`s.

Comment: Even without using UIBinder, you need to use RootLayoutPanel as long as you use any LayoutPanel components

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this next way:

```
<ui:style>
    .visible {
        overflow: visible !important;
    }
</ui:style>

<g:DockLayoutPanel unit="PX" width="100%" height="100%">
    <g:north size="46" styleName="{style.visible}">
         ...
    </g:north>
</g:DockLayoutPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works with small modifications:

- set style selector to ".visible > div" (div child of element with visible class is north element)
- add styleName (or better addStyleNames) to DockLayoutPanel

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
The important thing is, what is in the `center` widget. Example FlowPanel will fill out the area, but VerticalPanel not. Then you have to set the `height` property 100%.

Comment: You can see from the generated code that the second div has the correct absolute positioning.

Comment: You are right. Sorry, I was tired earlier. I edited my comment.